# How can I use edit_in_place in the show of a different model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inline-editing

I have a model Campaign and the campaign/show goes through a loop of the Emails.  Campaign has_many Emails.

```
<h2>Emails to Send Today</h2>

<% for email in @campaign.emails %>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong><%= link_to email.title, email_path(email) %> sent after 
       <%= distance_of_time_in_words(email.days.days) %></p>
<% end %>
```

I would like to be able to edit in place the subject and/or the email.days value from the Campaign/show page.

How do I do that?  (Added complexity, these are clickable links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will need to try again, don't seem to be getting any responses.